# WHS 2011 error code '2155348249' when trying to make a server backup: low disk space for Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS)

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-home-server, windows-server, volume-shadow-copy

When I try to start the windows server backup it fails because of empty disk space. I get the following error message in the event log:

> The backup operation that started at xxx has failed because the Volume
>   Shadow Copy Service operation to create a shadow copy of the volumes
>   being backed up failed with following error code '2155348249'. Please
>   review the event details for a solution, and then rerun the backup
>   operation once the issue is resolved.

The main drive C: has two partitions:

- Windows partition (normal drive you see in Windows)
- System backup (bootmgr, VSS, ...) 100 MB

The system backup partition has only ~5 MB free disk space and fails when trying to back up, but only if I include the system backup partition which is recommended.

I tried to [use C: for the VSS files](http://www.puryear-it.com/blog/2013/03/15/windows-server-backup-fails-when-backing-up-the-system-state/), but still I get the same error. I have enough space on my external backup media so it only has to do with the system backup partition.

How can I make the server backup?

Comment: Did you look in event viewer for the log it created?

Comment: What are you using for external backup storage?

Comment: The message I posted comes from the event viewer. Or what do you mean? External backup storage is a 1 TB HDD. The system drive I want to backup has 256 GB. So plenty of space.

Comment: Google returns nothing using that error code.

Comment: I have some results when I look after "windows home server error code 2155348249".